# Plotting horizontal and vertical lines in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, how do you plot a horizontal line at a given number? How do you plot a vertical line at a given number?

Comment: [This recent Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/08/10/mathematica-qa-combining-and-annotating-plots/) completely answers this question.

Answer (score 33):

If you're actually using [Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) (or [ListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html), et c.), the easiest solution is to use the [GridLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html) option, which lets you specify the *x*- and *y*-values where you want the lines drawn. For instance:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  GridLines -> {{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]/2, 2 \[Pi]},
                {-1, -Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2, 0, 1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}}]
```

[image: many lines]

**EDIT** to add:

Of course, this solution works if you just want to draw a line at a single, given number. For instance, if you want to reproduce the second example from [dreeve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901669/85467):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 GridLines -> {{4}, {}}]
```

[image: one line]

Answer (score 17):

For the case of horizontal lines when using `Plot` the easiest trick is to just include additional constant functions:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], .75}, {x, 0, 2Pi}]
```

For vertical lines, there's the `Epilog` option for `Plot` and `ListPlot`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}, Epilog->Line[{{4,-100}, {4,100}}]]
```

[image]

But probably the best is the `GridLines` option given in Pillsy's answer.

Comment: +1: I'd never thought of or come across the first suggestion you make @dreeves.

Answer (score 10):

One approach would be to add `Line` graphic primitives to your graphics:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi,2*Pi}];
l1 = Graphics@Line[{{-2Pi,.75},{2Pi,.75}}]; (* horizontal line at y==.75 *)
Show[p1,l1]
```

[image]

Another approach would be to fiddle around with `GridLines`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Gridlines command like so:

```
Plot[
  1/(15*E^((x - 100)^2/450)*Sqrt[2*Pi]),
  {x, 55, 145},
  GridLines -> {{85, 115}, {}}
]
```

TRANSLATION
In the code above I plot a normal curve:

```
1/(15*E^((x - 100)^2/450)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
```

Then tell the plot what part of the x-axis I want it to display:

```
{x, 55, 145}
```

Then I add the vertical gridlines where I want them at 85 and 115.

```
GridLines -> {{85, 115}, {}}
```

Note you need to provide the blank {} where `Gridlines` would expect the horizontal grid lines locations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to think of the vertical line as a straight line of infinite slope. So for a vertical line at located at x=2*pi, we can do something like this:

`Plot[{Sin[x], 10^10 (x - 2 \[Pi])}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]`

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D6pZ.png)

Note that the term 10^10 mimics an infinite slope. If you do not use the option PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, the "dominant" function is the straight line so the Sin[x] function do effectively appears as an horizontal line.